# Unmarshal and append to array go

Tags: json, go, amazon-s3

I'm reading a number of JSON files from S3, and want to return them all as one large JSON array. I have a struct matching my JSON data, and a for loop iterating over all objects in my s3 bucket. Each time I read, I unmarshal to my struct array. I want to append to my struct array so that I can get all the JSON data rather than just one file's data. Is there anyway to do this in Golang?

Comment: Did you try [append](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append)?

Comment: Do I need to make a temp slice to append though? B/c `Unmarshal` doesn't return anything, so can't append that.

Comment: You unmarshal the file into you struct value, then append the struct to the slice, after the loop is done you return the slice.

Comment: The file gets unmarshalled to a struct slice. I guess I need to just create a temp slice and append that to the main slice

Comment: Can you show some code? Why are you unmarshaling directly into a slice? Is the content of the file in `[{ ... }]` format? Or is there some other reason?

Comment: Yes the content of the file is in `[{....}]` format, which is why I'm unmarshaling into a slice

Comment: Then either append that slice *into* the final array which would result in a two dimensional array `[][]T`, or append only the 0th element of the unmarshaled slice if you know that only one element was unmarshaled, or "unpack" the unmarshaled slice... like so: https://play.golang.org/p/6SSLqD4-LF

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you should create a temporary array to Unmarshal the contents of each JSON, then append the items to your final result array in order to return the whole collection as one item.

See here an example of doing that.

In your case `input` would come from each of the S3 files you mention. Also, you would probably put that unmarshal logic in its own function to be able to call it for each input JSON.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

type Record struct {
    Author string `json:"author"`
    Title  string `json:"title"`
}

func main() {
    var allRecords []Record

    input := []byte(`[{
      "author": "Nirvana",
      "title":  "Smells like teen spirit"
    }, {
      "author": "The Beatles",
      "title":  "Help"
    }]`)

    var tmpRecords []Record
    err := json.Unmarshal(input, &tmpRecords)
    if (err != nil) {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    allRecords = append(allRecords, tmpRecords...)  

    fmt.Println("RECORDS:", allRecords)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/ZZGhy4UNhP

Comment: Please note there's no point in looping over `tmpRecords` as this `slice = append(slice, anotherSlice...)` does the same.